# Backwards Compatible Android/Java Code

Tags: java, android

I'm writing some code that is going to be used by some partners that maintain SDKs.  The SDKs are used by developers on Android 1.5 through 2.3.7.  My code uses features that are only available on 2.2 and later.  How can I write my code so developers using the partner SDKs don't get compile errors on Android < 2.2?

I tried using reflection and avoiding imports / declarations that used classes that weren't available before 2.2, but the code didn't work post 2.2 due to failure to dispatch to methods where I had changed the desired class type to Object.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to split up the code into a baseline (Android 1.5) and provide additional JAR(s) for higher API levels, similarly to how the [Android compat librabry](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) comes in a Android 1.6-compatible "v4" flavor and a "v11" for Android 3.2 and up.

At some points, you might also be able to take code from [AOSP](http://source.android.com/) and backport selected 2.2 features. I did this e.g. to be able to use `getExternalCacheDir()` on API level 7:

```
private static File getExternalCacheDir(final Context context) {
    // return context.getExternalCacheDir(); API level 8

    // e.g. "<sdcard>/Android/data/<package_name>/cache/"
    final File extCacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "/Android/data/" + context.getApplicationInfo().packageName + "/cache/");
    extCacheDir.mkdirs();
    return extCacheDir;
}
```

Reflection-heavy code will be maintenance nightmare -- as much as you want to avoid those red compiler error dongles for your customers/partners, *you* want to see them instead of some obscure runtime exception caused by outdated constants in your reflection code.

Comment: So it sounds like any non-reflection based solution will require some action on the end user's (developer's) part.  I was hoping to avoid that as I doubt we'll be able to convince our partners to require a more complicated integration from their SDK users.

Comment: They would need to drop in the right JARs into the `lib` folder depending on `android:minSdkVersion`, that shouldn't be too hard. Argue with the increased code quality/stability of a non/minimally-reflection-based approach -- that usually translates directly into less cost.